# Python 3: urllib returning � characters when trying to unquote a string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, urllib

I'm trying to unquote a string, retrieved from a href via Selenium:

`DOC.01-PROCURA%C7%C3O.pdf`

When I try to use urllib.parse.unquote or urllib.parse.unquote_plus in Python 3, both of them returns the following:

`'DOC.01-PROCURA��O.pdf'`

How do I get rids of these � chars? It was supposed to return `DOC.01-PROCURAÇÃO.pdf`, because Selenium downloads a pdf file with this filename, which I will find it later via `os.path.exists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib.parse.unquote` defaults to decoding as UTF-8.  In this case, `Windows-1252` works:

```
>>> s = 'DOC.01-PROCURA%C7%C3O.pdf'
>>> urllib.parse.unquote(s,'Windows-1252')
'DOC.01-PROCURAÇÃO.pdf'
```

Check the encoding of the page the data came from.

Comment: It worked. Thanks! By the way, how do I know which encoding was used in a string?

Comment: @ayrtondenner it’s a common one and I just tried it, but it should be retrievable from the page’s metadata.